# Connection String With Password? (Access 2010)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have this connection string;

```
PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database\Organizations.accdb;
```

I set a password for the database, now what I want to know ***if it is possible that I can put a password in the string?*** like:

```
PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Database\Organizations.accdb;Password=mypassword;
```

I searched all over the internet for a while but I can't seem to find what Im asking although I found something that ALMOST it, but doesn't work at all. Thank you so much.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: Honestly, I tried that one lately, but when I did it the second time it works, I just forgot to delete my .exe from the debug folder which sometimes VB fails to refresh it with the new one with the new code. Thanks anyways, it worked now.